# online convex programming software

Tags: optimization, convex

I am looking for a software which does convex optimization in an online learning way. When I have a new observation I don't want to run the optimization program from the beginning, but to update the current model based on the new observation. A survey on this problem can be found at http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/OLsurvey.pdf

Is there any well implemented software for doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: I haven't applied convex optimization in machine learning but these might be helpful:
1) http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/links.html (See Software section),
2) http://www.stanford.edu/~liszt90/spy11.pdf